# DataTables bower update error (multi platform)

Tags: linux, windows, datatables, bower

This doesn't come to our colleague who has Mac, but my other colleague with Windows experienced it recently also. We have bower taking care of the JS libraries in our application, and often times when I `bower update`, I'm facing:

```
λ bower update
bower                       EMALFORMED Failed to read C:\Users\uname\Documents\repo\bower\DataTables\.bower.json
Additional error details:
Unexpected token }
```

(I'm using `Cmder`, that's the `λ` prompt).
The computer is always right, and if I navigate to the referred file, it visibly has a second closing curly brace at the end.

```
{
  "name": "datatables",
  "main": [
    "media/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
    "media/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
    "media/images/sort_asc.png",
    "media/images/sort_asc_disabled.png",
    "media/images/sort_both.png",
    "media/images/sort_desc.png",
    "media/images/sort_desc_disabled.png"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.7.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "jquery",
    "datatables",
    "table",
    "javascript",
    "library"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "/.*",
    "examples",
    "media/unit_testing",
    "composer.json",
    "dataTables.jquery.json",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables",
  "version": "1.10.11",
  "_release": "1.10.11",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "1.10.11",
    "commit": "8a3412a1aee8fdb4b65f426faa6c9a986994abfe"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/DataTables/DataTables.git",
  "_target": "~1.10.11",
  "_originalSource": "DataTables"
}}
```

How can I avoid this? What is causing this? I assume that this `bower.json` starting with a period is coming from the server or a result of an intermediate build step. I want to find the root cause so this won't happen again. If I manually remove the extra curly brace the bower build succeeds, but I have to do that often times. Or is this a problem with `DataTables` + Windows + `bower`?

---

Update: still having the issue on Windows (Win 10 64 bit), I have it now on Linux too:

```
Bower version: 1.7.7
Node version: 0.10.25
OS: Linux 4.4.0-x86_64-linode63 x64
(env)user@server:/opt/webapps/sportsboard/env/westshoretech$ bower update --force
bower                       EMALFORMED Failed to read /opt/webapps/blabla/env/product/bower/DataTables/.bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected end of input
```

Comment: Still suffering from the same thing. I cannot believe noone else experience this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and the solution was changing the name of the bower dependency from "datatables" to "datatables.net", which is the name listed in the [docs](https://datatables.net/download/bower).

Comment: Good point. In another project I use another set of packages and those work fine